# Display multiple API info in Tkinter Output Box

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I have a tkinter app that display some info in a text widget box.
It collects data from an API and then displays the output.  If I collect a single bit of info it works fine.  But I am trying to display multiple lines of info.
It works fine in python using this code:

```
import sys
import requests
import urllib3
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json


urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

#NetMRI Info
username = "test"
password = 'test'

DEVICE ='test_device'
url = 'https://test/api/3.7/infra_devices/search?DeviceName=' + DEVICE

#response Data
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), verify=False)
data = response.json()

for ID in data['infra_devices']:
    print("Device ID= " + ID['DeviceID'], "DeviceModel= " + ID['DeviceModel'],sep='\n')
```

Output shows in console like:

**Device ID= 324770**

**DeviceModel= ASR1001X**

**Process finished with exit code 0**

I then have this code for tkinter app:

```
def button_get_info():
    d = device.get()

    url = 'https://test/api/3.7/infra_devices/search?DeviceName=' + d
    response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), verify=False)
    data = response.json()
    for ID in data['infra_devices']:
        print_out.insert("end-1c", "Device ID= " + ID['DeviceID'], "DeviceModel= " + ID['DeviceModel'])
```

But it only ever shows:

**Device ID= 324770**

It doesn't show the other line/output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The third argument of `Text.insert()` is the tag for the text inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `insert` method takes an index, a string to print, an optional tag, and additional optional string, tag combinations (eg: `insert(index, string, tag, string, tag, ...`)

When you do `print_out.insert("end-1c", "Device ID= " + ID['DeviceID'], "DeviceModel= " + ID['DeviceModel'])` you are passing an index and then two more arguments. The string to be printed is `"Device ID= " + ID['DeviceID']`, and the next argument is treated as a tag so it won't appear as text.

A simple solution is to join these two strings before calling `insert`. To make your code easier to test I recommend creating the string and inserting the string as separate lines of code, and use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) instead of concatenation.

```
for ID in data['infra_devices']:
    s = f"Device ID= {ID['DeviceID']}\nDeviceModel= {ID['DeviceModel']}\n"
    print_out.insert("end-1c",s)
```